# How do I delete or clear data that has been copied to a different text box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a simple calculator that adds two numbers and displays the result in a different box. I have figured out how to copy text from one box and display it in another, but I am stuck on how to clear it. The data from the original textboxes will clear, but not from the textboxes in the display box. Below is the code for the html, css, and js files.

```js
 function startOver() {
     document.demo_form.txt1.value="";
     document.demo_form.txt2.value="";
     document.demo_info.txtresult.value="";
     document.getElementById("demo_info").innerHTML="";
        }

 
        function copy() {
     var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
     var field1 = document.getElementById("field1");
     field1.value=txt1.value;
        var txt2 = document.getElementById("txt2");
     var field2 = document.getElementById("field2");
     field2.value=txt2.value;
        }
 
 
        function calculate(){
     var q=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
     var w=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);

     var result=q+w;
  if(isNaN(q)||isNaN(w)){
        alert("please enter a number");
  }
  else
        {
  var result=q+w;
  
        document.getElementById("txtresult").value=result;
        }
        }
```

```css
        #container {
     width:650px;
     height:450px;
     margin:0px auto;
     padding:10px;
     background-color:white;
     border:1px solid black;
        }

        #demo_src {
     float: left;
     width: 250px;
     height: 220px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     }

        #demo_info {
     float: right;
     width: 350px;
     height: 220px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border: 1px solid orange;
        }

        #table_header {
     clear: both;
     width: 649px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #table {
     overflow: auto;
     width: 649px;
     height: 20px;
     border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #table {
     align: center;
     font-family: Sans-serif;
     font-size: 13px;
        }
```

```html
  <div id="container">
  <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
  <div id="demo_src">
  <form name="demo_form">
  <table style=margin:10px;>
  <tr>
  <td>Enter the First Number:</td>
  <td><input type = "text" name="txt1" id="txt1" size = "10"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Enter the Second Number:</td>
  <td><input type = "text" name="txt2" id="txt2" size = "10"/></td>
  </tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="calculate(); 
        copy()"/></td>
  <td><input type = "button" onclick = "startOver()"   
        value = "Start Over"/></td>
  </table>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div id = "demo_info">
  <table style=margin:10px;>
  <tr>
  <td>Field 1:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" size="15"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Field 2:</td>
  <td><input type = "text" name="field2" id="field2" size = "15"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>Result: </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="txtresult" size="10"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>   
  </div>
  </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting children elements by dot is OK in FORM and its children INPUTs and just by their **NAME** but won't work for Parent and deep Children in other HTML elements. You can simply get that element by ID instead:

```
document.getElementById("txtresult").value="";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="reset" value="Start Over">
```

should work inside a form tag to reset the inputs inside a form **without the need for any additional javascript to reset inputs** values, in this case you can remove `startOver()` function when you use `input type="reset"`. If you insist on using javascript then go with the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function startOver() {
        document.getElementById("demo_form_id").reset();
        document.getElementById("field1").value="";
        document.getElementById("field2").value="";
        document.getElementById("txtresult").value="";
        }

 
        function copy() {
     var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
     var field1 = document.getElementById("field1");
     field1.value=txt1.value;
        var txt2 = document.getElementById("txt2");
     var field2 = document.getElementById("field2");
     field2.value=txt2.value;
        }
 
 
        function calculate(){
     var q=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
     var w=parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);

     var result=q+w;
  if(isNaN(q)||isNaN(w)){
        alert("please enter a number");
  }
  else
        {
  var result=q+w;
  
        document.getElementById("txtresult").value=result;
        }
        }
```

```css
        #container {
     width:650px;
     height:450px;
     margin:0px auto;
     padding:10px;
     background-color:white;
     border:1px solid black;
        }

        #demo_src {
     float: left;
     width: 250px;
     height: 220px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border: 1px solid blue;
     }

        #demo_info {
     float: right;
     width: 350px;
     height: 220px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border: 1px solid orange;
        }

        #table_header {
     clear: both;
     width: 649px;
     height: 50px;
     border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #table {
     overflow: auto;
     width: 649px;
     height: 20px;
     border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #table {
     align: center;
     font-family: Sans-serif;
     font-size: 13px;
        }
```

```html
  <div id="container">
  <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
  <div id="demo_src">
  <form name="demo_form" id="demo_form_id">
  <table style=margin:10px;>
  <tr>
  <td>Enter the First Number:</td>
  <td><input type = "text" name="txt1" id="txt1" size = "10"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Enter the Second Number:</td>
  <td><input type = "text" name="txt2" id="txt2" size = "10"/></td>
  </tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="calculate(); 
        copy()"/></td>
  <td><input type = "button" onclick = "startOver()"   
        value = "Start Over"/></td>
  </table>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div id = "demo_info">
  <table style=margin:10px;>
  <tr>
  <td>Field 1:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" size="15"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Field 2:</td>
  <td><input type = "text" name="field2" id="field2" size = "15"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td>Result: </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="txtresult" size="10"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>   
  </div>
  </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This worked great, and I learned something new.